# Exception Handling giving me trouble

Tags: java, exception

I have a small program I am working on. I Just put a try catch in my code and everything seems to be working except for 1 thing. I will post my code below...  As you can see my try catch statement in my code it tells the program to go down to the checkNumber method for exception handling. I keep getting an error on this part...

```
if (input == 5){
}
```

The input keeps underlining red and saying "Incompatible operand types scanner and int.

Not sure what the problem is... or how to fix it.. here is my code

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

    public class BankMain
    {
    private double availableBal =80;
    private double totalBal =100;
    private double availableBal2 =480;
    private double totalBal2 =500;
    private double availableBal3 =80;
    private double totalBal3 =100;
    ArrayList<Integer> cardNum = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    private String error;           //String the error from the exception
    {
        error = "error";
    }


    public void cardNumbers(){


            Scanner cards = new Scanner(System.in);
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);



            try{


            System.out.println("Please select a 5 digit card number");

            cardNum.add(input.nextInt());
            checkNumber();


            }

            catch(invalidNumber err){

                System.out.println("Caught Error: " + err.getError());
            }

            System.out.println("Thank you! You're card number is " +cardNum);

            System.out.println("Type 'c' to go back to main menu.");
            String value = keyboard.next();

            if(value.equalsIgnoreCase("c")){
                menu();

    }

    else if (!keyboard.equals('c')){

        System.out.println("Invalid Entry!");

    }

}


    public void menu(){

    System.out.println("ATM Menu:");
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("1 = Create Account");
    System.out.println("2 = Account Login");
    System.out.println("3 = Exit ATM");
    query();
                }

        public void startAtm()
        {
            menu();

        }



        public void drawMainMenu()
        {

            AccountMain main3 = new AccountMain();
            int selection;

            System.out.println("\nATM main menu:");
            System.out.println("1 - View account balance");
            System.out.println("2 - Withdraw funds");
            System.out.println("3 - Add funds");
            System.out.println("4 - Back to Account Menu");
            System.out.println("5 - Terminate transaction");
            System.out.print("Choice: ");
            selection =input.nextInt();

            switch(selection)
            {
            case 1:
                viewAccountInfo();
                break;
            case 2:
                withdraw();
                break;
            case 3:
                addFunds();
                break;
            case 4:
                AccountMain.selectAccount();
                break;
            case 5:
                System.out.println("Thank you for using this ATM!!! goodbye");
            }
        }

        public void viewAccountInfo()
        {
            System.out.println("Account Information:");
            System.out.println("\t--Total balance: $"+totalBal);
            System.out.println("\t--Available balance: $"+availableBal);
            drawMainMenu();
        }

        public void viewAccountInfo2()
        {
            System.out.println("Account Information:");
            System.out.println("\t--Total balance: $"+totalBal2);
            System.out.println("\t--Available balance: $"+availableBal2);
            drawMainMenu();
        }

        public void deposit(int depAmount)
        {
            System.out.println("\n***Please insert your money now...***");
            totalBal =totalBal +depAmount;
            availableBal =availableBal +depAmount;
        }

        public void checkNsf(int withdrawAmount)
        {
            if(totalBal -withdrawAmount < 0)
                System.out.println("\n***ERROR!!! Insufficient funds in you accout***");
            else
            {
                totalBal =totalBal -withdrawAmount;
                availableBal =availableBal -withdrawAmount;
                System.out.println("\n***Please take your money now...***");
                }
        }

        public void addFunds()
        {
            int addSelection;

            System.out.println("Deposit funds:");
            System.out.println("1 - $20");
            System.out.println("2 - $40");
            System.out.println("3 - $60");
            System.out.println("4 - $100");
            System.out.println("5 - Back to main menu");
            System.out.print("Choice: ");
            addSelection =input.nextInt();

            switch(addSelection)
            {
            case 1:
                deposit(20);
                drawMainMenu();
                break;
            case 2:
                deposit(40);
                drawMainMenu();
                break;
            case 3:
                deposit(60);
                drawMainMenu();
                break;
            case 4:
                deposit(100);
                drawMainMenu();
                break;
            case 5:
                drawMainMenu();
                break;
            }
        }

        public void withdraw()
        {
            int withdrawSelection;

            System.out.println("Withdraw money:");
            System.out.println("1 - $20");
            System.out.println("2 - $40");
            System.out.println("3 - $60");
            System.out.println("4 - $100");
            System.out.println("5 - Back to main menu");
            System.out.print("Choice: ");
            withdrawSelection =input.nextInt();

            switch(withdrawSelection)
            {
            case 1:
                checkNsf(20);
                drawMainMenu();
                break;
            case 2:
                checkNsf(40);
                drawMainMenu();
                break;
            case 3:
                checkNsf(60);
                drawMainMenu();
                break;
            case 4:
                checkNsf(100);
                drawMainMenu();
                break;
            case 5:
                drawMainMenu();
                break;
            }
        }

public void query(){

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    double input = keyboard.nextInt();  


    if (input == 2){

        BankMainPart2 main2 = new BankMainPart2();

        System.out.println("Please enter your 5 digit card number.");
         BankMainPart2.loginCard(cardNum);



    }
    else if (input == 1){

        cardNumbers();

    }

    else if (input == 3){
        System.out.println("Thank you, have a nice day!");
        System.exit(0);


    }

}

public void checkingMenu()
{

    AccountMain main3 = new AccountMain();
    int selection;

    System.out.println("\nATM main menu:");
    System.out.println("1 - View account balance");
    System.out.println("2 - Withdraw funds");
    System.out.println("3 - Add funds");
    System.out.println("4 - Back to Account Menu");
    System.out.println("5 - Terminate transaction");
    System.out.print("Choice: ");
    selection =input.nextInt();

    switch(selection)
    {
    case 1:
        viewAccountInfo2();
        break;
    case 2:
        withdraw();
        break;
    case 3:
        addFunds();
        break;
    case 4:
        AccountMain.selectAccount();
        break;
    case 5:
        System.out.println("Thank you for using this ATM!!! goodbye");
    }
}

private static void checkNumber() throws invalidNumber              //run the check activation exception
{
  if (input == 5)
  {
      System.out.println("");
  }
  else
     throw new invalidNumber("invalid number");
 }  

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        BankMain myAtm = new BankMain();
        myAtm.startAtm();
    }
}
```

Class Bank Main 2

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class BankMainPart2 {

    public static void loginCard(ArrayList<Integer> cardNum){

        BankMain main = new BankMain();
        AccountMain main3 = new AccountMain();

        Scanner logNum = new Scanner(System.in);    

        int loginInput = logNum.nextInt();

        if (cardNum.contains(loginInput)) {

            main3.selectAccount();

        }

        else {

            System.out.println("Sorry, that pin number is incorrect!");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your variable `input` is an object of `Scanner` which is declared globally and will be used for the method `checknumber()` and `5` is an `int`. Hence they are incompatible types.

The same statement works for method `query()` because for query you have locally defined a variable `input` which is of the type `double`.

What you should actually write is

```
if(input.nextInt() == 5){}
```

Comment: Ah thanks a lot, one other quick question... If I want my program to say... if the number the user enters is < or > than 5 then the error will come up but it if is == 5 then they are good?

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly you've asked but you're function right now discards anything that is not 5 and processes only 5. so that seems fine.

Comment: Sorry about that let me ask this, now when I put that code in that you told me to use it asks me to enter the number twice before it checks if its valid or not for example the output before was just.."please enter a card number 5 digits" then i would type it in and the program would continue now it says "please enter a card number 5 digits" and then i type it in 544432 and then hit enter and nothing happens so i type it again 544432 and then hit enter and it says invalid number

Comment: So how would I make it so it would just error check it on the first time i type it in instead of making me type it twice before the program goes, because something is holding it back right now.

Comment: It could be something to do with your BankMainPart2 class that you havent mentioned here.